# Как изменить размер консольного окна?

Tags: c++, windows

Как изменить размер консольного окна?

```
HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
RECT r;
GetWindowRect(console, &r); //stores the console's current dimensions

MoveWindow(console, r.left, r.top, 800, 100, TRUE); // 800 width, 100 height
```

Работает лишь по вертикали.

Comment: Может окно уже 800 в ширину? И что возвращает функция, true?

Comment: Нет, если больше ставлю - ничего не изменяется.

Comment: Ну, как бы размер по вертикали изменяется.

Comment: Ширина консольного окна наверное зависит от размера шрифта и ширины строки. Т.е. просто выставить ширину в пикселях наверное не получится.

Comment: Возможно это. http://snap.ashampoo.com/JbFcu4uP

Answer (score 1):

Ну, в Delphi, когда нужно ручками поменять размер консоли, я использую давно написанную функцию:

```
function SetConsoleSize(newx,newy:integer):integer;
var
  Rect: TSmallRect;
  MaxSize,Coord: TCoord;
begin
  MaxSize:=GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
  if (newx > MaxSize.X) or ((newx > MaxSize.X)) then
     begin
      Result:=-1; // возвращаем -1, если пытаемся задать очень большой размер
      exit;
     end;
  Rect.Left := 1;
  Rect.Top := 1;
  Rect.Right := newx+1;
  Rect.Bottom := newy+1;
  Coord.X := Rect.Right + 1 - Rect.Left; // размеры окна должны быть хотя бы на 1 меньше буфера
  Coord.y := Rect.Bottom + 1 - Rect.Top;
  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Coord); // выставляем размер буфера
  Result:=integer(SetConsoleWindowInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), True, Rect)); // выставляем размер окна
end;
```

Понимаю, что ответ должен быть на C++, но на этой машине нет С++, проверить правильность кода не могу, поэтому сейчас дам пояснения, чтобы легко можно было перевести с Delphi на C++.

Вначале нам необходимо определить максимально возможный размер окна. Делаем это функцией [`COORD WINAPI GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(HANDLE hConsoleOutput);`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getlargestconsolewindowsize), передавая в качестве параметра handle нашего окна, получая в COORD макс значения X и Y. Структура COORD:

```
typedef struct _COORD {
  SHORT X;
  SHORT Y;
} COORD, *PCOORD;
```

Если всё в порядке, нужно задать координаты, для этого используется структура SMALL_RECT:

```
typedef struct _SMALL_RECT {
  SHORT Left;
  SHORT Top;
  SHORT Right;
  SHORT Bottom;
} SMALL_RECT;
```

и новый размер буфера (опять-таки через COORD). Нужно помнить, чтобы новые размеры были применены успешно, размер буфера должен быть хотя бы на 1 больше, чем размер окна. Дальше просто: используем функции [`BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(_In_ HANDLE hConsoleOutput, COORD  dwSize);`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbuffersize) для задания нового размера буфера и [`BOOL WINAPI SetConsoleWindowInfo(HANDLE hConsoleOutput, BOOL bAbsolute, const SMALL_RECT *lpConsoleWindow);`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo) для задания нового размера. Возвращаем результат, если нужно.